# Find minimum function satisfies recursive definition

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, analysis, functions

Assume $k$ is a large enough positive integer. For all integers $\ell$ with $k^{3/4}\le \ell\le k$, function $f$ satisfies
$$f(\ell-1)+\ell \le f(\ell),$$
$$f(\ell)\ge \frac{\ell^2}{\log \ell}.$$
Does there exist some $f$ satisfy both above assumptions and $f(\ell)\ll l^2$ (to be clear, $f(\ell)=o(\ell^2)$)  for all $k^{3/4}\le \ell\le k$? If so, what is the minimum possible $f$ (to be clear, in pointwise sense)? 

**New question:** If not, is it possible to find $f$ satisfying both above assumptions and $\sum_{\ell=k^{3/4}}^kf(\ell)=o(k^3)$?

My rough opinion: Viewing $f$ as a function on real numbers, it seems its derivative is linear (this observation is not strict because $f$ only needs to be defined on those integers), so it is at least a quadratic function. But I am not sure if we can make it smaller.

Comment: Just a thought: try playing with factors of $\log\log n$ etc, maybe you can affect the function $f(x)=x^2$ slightly, without violating the constraints..

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "minimum possible $f$"? Is it that the function $f(l) = O(l^k)$ for the smallest positive $k$, it has the smallest maximum, if it's a polynomial that it is of the least degree, or something else?

Comment: For example, if you can find $f_1(\ell)=\ell^2/\log \ell$ and $f_2(\ell)=\ell^2/\log\log\ell$ satisfies both assumptions (in fact neither of them satisfies the first one), then $f_1$ is smaller than $f_2$. (Recall $k$ is very large, so is $\ell$ in the range.)

Comment: Your conditions impose *no* constraints on the values of $f$ at non-integers *whatsoever*. So viewing $f$ as a real function makes little sense; taking its derivative makes even less sense. Did you mean to assum that $f$ is a differentiable/smooth function on $[k^{3/4},k]$? Even then in makes little sense; between the integer values you can make $f$ go as low as you like.

Comment: No. It only needs to be defined on all integers in this interval.

Comment: The new question is even more problematic...  $\sum_{\ell=k^{3/4}}^k f(\ell)$ is a function of $k$, not of $\ell$.  (There is no $\ell$ in the sum.)  Do you want it to be $o(k^3)$?  But this runs into the issues I discussed in my answer (i.e. do you care about just a specific $k$ or for all large enough $k$...)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It was a typo. It should be $o(k^3)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $k>1$ and let $a:=\lceil k^{3/4}\rceil$ and $b:=\lfloor k\rfloor$. You are looking for a sequence $x_a,\ldots,x_b\in\Bbb{R}$ satisfying
$$x_n\geq\frac{n^2}{\ln{n}}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad x_n\geq x_{n-1}+n,$$
where I assume $x_0\in\Bbb{R}$ is unrestricted. Of course if $x_n\geq\frac{n^2}{\ln{n}}$ then
$$x_{n+1}\geq x_n+n+1\geq\frac{n^2}{\ln{n}}+n+1\geq\frac{(n+1)^2}{\ln(n+1)},$$
where we use the fact that $n\geq a\geq2$. So it suffices to find a sequence $x_a,\ldots,x_b\in\Bbb{R}$ satisfying
$$x_a\geq\frac{a^2}{\ln a}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad x_n\geq x_{n-1}+n.$$
It is then clear that the minimal such sequence is given by
$$x_n=\frac{a^2}{\ln{a}}+\sum_{i=a}^n(i-a)=\frac{a^2}{\ln{a}}+\frac12(n-a)(n-a+1).$$
Or in terms of your original question
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(\ell)
&=&\frac{\lceil k^{3/4}\rceil^2}{\ln\lceil k^{3/4}\rceil}
+\frac12(\ell-\lceil k^{3/4}\rceil)(\ell-\lceil k^{3/4}\rceil+1)\\
&=&\frac12\ell^2+\frac{1-2\lceil k^{3/4}\rceil}{2}\ell-\frac{\lceil k^{3/4}\rceil(\lceil k^{3/4}\rceil-1)}{2}+\frac{\lceil k^{3/4}\rceil^2}{\ln\lceil k^{3/4}\rceil}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This also allows for a closed form for the sum $\sum_{\ell=k^{3/4}}^kf(\ell)$, which is however rather unwieldy.

**Added later:** Here's the unwieldy expression:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{\ell=a}^bf(\ell)
&=&\frac{1}{12}(b-(a-1))\left(2b^2+2(a-1)b+2(a-1)^2+3b+3(a-1)+1\right)\\
&\ &+\frac{1-2a}{4}(b-(a-1))(b+(a-1)+1)\\
&\ &-(b-(a-1))\left(\frac{a(a-1)}{2}-\frac{a^2}{\ln{a}}\right)\\
&=&\frac{b-a+1}{6}\left(b^2-2ab-5a^2+2b+4a+\frac{6a^2}{\ln{a}}\right)\\
&=&\frac16(b-a+1)\left((b-a)^2+2(b-a)-6a\left(a-1-\frac{a}{\ln{a}}\right)\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
You can plug in $a=\lceil k^{3/4}\rceil$ and $b=\lfloor k\rfloor$ to get the desired closed form for the sum. As for the asymptotic behaviour of the sum: Set $c:=k^{1/4}$ so that $b\leq c^4$ and $a\geq c^3$. Then by basic calculus
$$a\left(a-1-\frac{a}{\ln{a}}\right)
\geq c^3\left(c^3-1-\frac{c^3}{\ln{c^3}}\right),$$
and $b-a\leq c^4-c^3$, from which it follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{\ell=a}^bf(\ell)
&\leq&\frac{1}{12}(c^4-c^3+1)
\left((c^4-c^3)^2+2(c^4-c^3)-6c^3\left(c^3-1-\frac{c^3}{\ln{c^3}}\right)\right),\\
&=&\frac{1}{12}(c^4-c^3+1)
\left(c^8-2c^7-5c^6+2c^4+4c^3+\frac{2c^6}{\ln{c}}\right),\\
&=&\frac{1}{12}\left(c^{12}-3c^{11}
-\left(3-\tfrac{2}{\ln{c}}\right)c^{10}
+\left(5-\tfrac{2}{\ln{c}}\right)c^9
+3c^8
-\left(9-\tfrac{2}{\ln{c}}\right)c^6+2c^4+4c^3\right),
\end{eqnarray*}
which is *not* $o(c^{12})$ and hence *not* $o(k^3)$.

Comment: First, the sum is a function of $k$, not $\ell$.  So are we discussing whether the sum is $o(k^3)$?  I don't think I see easily why the sum is $o(k^3)$ (small-o, not big-O)...

Comment: @antkam I was too quick to conclude that the sum is $o(k^3)$; I have added more details on why it is *not* $o(k^3)$. I think I was originally expecting the leading term to be $\tfrac{k^3}{\ln{k}}$ but it turns out to be $k^3$.

Comment: +1.  This is a great answer.  You basically considered $f(k,\ell)$ already, i.e. allow $f(\ell)$ to change depending on $k$.  And you proved that, even if you start as low as possible (for any $k$) and add as little as possible (i.e. $\ell$) per step, the relevant $\sum_\ell f(k,\ell) =\Theta(k^3)$.

Answer (score 0):

One heuristic approach:

Solve for $f(l)$ using $f(l)=f(l-1)+l$. This gives the minimum possible $f$ that satisfies the inequality. Assuming that the derivate of $f$ is linear, let $f(l)=\alpha l^2+\beta l+\gamma$. On solving for $f$, we get that $f(l) = \frac{1}{2}l^2-\frac{1}{2}l+\gamma.$

Next, we use $f(l)\geq \frac{l^2}{\log(l)}$ to compute $\gamma$. Since both $f(l)$ and $ \frac{l^2}{\log(l)}$ are increasing function of $l\geq 1$, we get
\begin{equation}
\gamma = \frac{4k^{3/2}}{3\log(k)} - \frac{1}{2}k^{3/2}-\frac{1}{2}k^{3/4}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.  IMHO the question is somewhat ill-defined.

**First interpretation:** If you care about only a particular $k$, e.g. $k=10^8$, then in fact $f(\ell) \le f(k)$ which can be considered a constant (after fixing any choice of $f$), so $f(\ell) = O(1) = o(\ell^2)$ since you can allow the hidden constant to depend on $k=10^8$.  E.g. pick $f(\ell) = \ell^2$ in the range $[10^6, 10^8]$, and it is technically true that $f(\ell) \le 10^{16}$ so it is $O(1)$.

**Second interpretation:** OTOH, if you want the hidden constant to be independent of $k$, what exactly does the question mean?  Does it mean it must work for all (large enough) $k$?  I.e., must it be true that, $\exists K$ s.t. $\forall k > K: f(\ell) \ge f(\ell-1) + \ell$?  If so, it seems obvious that $f$ must grow at least quadratically as $\ell \rightarrow +\infty$.

**Third interpretation:** perhaps you would like some "nice looking" function such as $f(\ell) = {\alpha \ell^2 \over \log \log \ell}$ to satisfy your requirements.  But in fact, this boils down to the same issue!  I.e. if your requirements must be met for all large enough $k$, then it is impossible.  But if your requirements must only be met for a certain $k$ e.g. $k=10^8$, then simply adjust $\alpha$ s.t. it meets all your requirements in the fixed range $[10^6, 10^8]$.  I haven't tried this but for a (really) large $\alpha$ I'd think you can meet both the difference requirement and the $f(\ell) \ge \ell^2 / \log \ell$ requirement.

Comment: Here $k$ is treated as an asymptotic parameter tending to infinity (as indicated by the little o notation), i.e., your second interpretation. It seems true that $f$ is quadratic if we require $f$ to be smooth on $[k^{3/4},k]$. But what happens if we only require $f$ to be defined on integers in that interval?

Comment: Smoothness didn't matter.  The key idea is in the answer by @Servaes, i.e. for any $k$, the minimal sequence happens when you start as low as possible (constrained by $f(\ell) \ge \ell^2 / \log \ell$) and then add the smallest amount ($\ell$) per step.  This is $x_n=\frac{a^2}{\ln{a}}+\sum_{i=a}^n(i-a)=\frac{a^2}{\ln{a}}+\frac12(n-a)(n-a+1)$ in that answer, but that answer further shows that, even for this procedure, you cannot satisfy $\sum = o(k^3)$.